# Wordpress Custom Post Type While Loop Breaking PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, custom-post-type

My While loop is breaking the rest of my PHP on the site. I am using Advanced Custom Fields also as a reference. Below I put my code that is working but again breaking the rest of the site (and or anything below this).

Any Suggestions
Thank You For the Help I have stuck for to long!

```
<?php 
    $query = array( 'post_type' => 'slides', 'orderby' => 'ASC' );
    $loop = new WP_Query($query);
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $image_object = get_field('slides');
        $alt = $image_object['title'];
        $sizes = $image_object['sizes'];
        $image = $sizes['slider'];

        echo '<div>';
        echo '<div class="slide">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add [wp_reset_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) after your custom loop:

```
<?php 
    $query = array( 'post_type' => 'slides', 'orderby' => 'ASC' );
    $loop = new WP_Query($query);
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $image_object = get_field('slides');
        $alt = $image_object['title'];
        $sizes = $image_object['sizes'];
        $image = $sizes['slider'];

        echo '<div>';
        echo '<div class="slide">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```